# Question: Japanese scientific article on satoyama

Tags: grammar

I need to read this article for my class, and I can't seem to get past this sentence:

> つまり、政治的にも巧みに利用されがちな「ふるさと」や「原風景」と接続する既成概念としての 「里」が喚起する感情・感傷に無批判に安住するの**ではなく**、私たちが位置する所与の場所の意味を内省的に深く洞察し、暮らしの形を新たに構想してゆく過程が求められるのである。

The words are not the problem, the grammatical structure however is killing me. Can anyone help me translate it?

EDIT: Oh aha I'm sorry, I'll try to explain it better:

I can't decide to where dewa naku refers to (i know it belongs with 無批判に安住するの) but does it belong with the rest of the sentence, or is the part behind the point (・) to the (,) a sentence on its own?

Comment: You should provide your attempt at translation and highlight which grammar aspects you're stuck on, otherwise this will get closed as "we don't do translation", or "this question shows no research effort".

Answer (score 3):

That `ではなく` denies almost everything before it. The basic structure is:

> つまり、 `A` ではなく、 `B` が求められるのである。
>   Therefore, not `A` but `B` is required.

Where:

- A is `政治的にも巧みに利用されがちな「ふるさと」や「原風景」と接続する既成概念としての 「里」が喚起する感情・感傷に無批判に安住する(こと)`
- B is `私たちが位置する所与の場所の意味を内省的に深く洞察し、暮らしの形を新たに構想してゆく過程`